# How can I set the  Canon EOS 500D interval timer to take 10 photos with a 10 second interval?

Tags: canon, canon-500d, camera-settings, intervalometer

I am using Canon EOS 500D, with Canon EF 1.8 USM Portrait Lens.

I would like to set a self timer continuous in drive mode for capturing 10 images continuously **with 10 second intervals between the photos**.

I achieved this in **P** (Program Mode) somehow accidentally yesterday to take portraits of my wife and myself.

Today I changed some settings and I am getting only 10 pictures continuously taken with 1 sec interval. We are in a holiday right now, trying to take our couple portraits in a self continuous drive mode. I am vexed as I could not achieve this. For your additional info, I have the Canon remote as well. I tried all the drive modes to achieve this again, but I failed to conquer it.

Lot many people are confused with the similar issue for more info

http://photography-on-the.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-648397.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option, and i guess that is what you activated can be found here:
[image]

> The Canon T2i's Drive setting also accesses three Self-Timer modes,
>   which open the shutter 10 or 2 seconds after the Shutter button is
>   pressed, giving you time to dash around in front of the camera. The
>   third mode will take a programmable amount of shots (2 to 10 shots),
>   after a 10 second delay. A Remote Control mode works with the
>   dedicated and wireless remote units as well. [source](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/T2I/T2IA5.HTM)

(also accesible for the 500d)

My second suggestion is the **[Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki) addon** for the canon (compatible with canon 500d).

By adding this firmware to the camera you will have access to the integrated intervalometer where you can set the amount of time between shots.

(This firmware addon adds a lot of new tools apart from the intervalometer. (focus peak, exposure braketing, stack focus, follow focus You can find out more about the magic lantern firmware on this site: [Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki))

> [Intervalometer](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified/UserGuide#intervalometer)
>
> Intervalometer: ON/OFF
>
> Take pictures or movies at fixed intervals.
>   You can stop the intervalometer by rotating the mode dial.
>   Settings:
>   Duration between two shots.
>   Bulb ramping option (see below).
>   In movie mode only: duration of a movie clip.

I have been using this firmware addon in combination with the Canon 550D for over a year now for creating Timelapses and long exposures.

Even for a beginner Magic Lantern is simple to install and use.

Comment: Thanks for the info I never heard about Magic Lantern. Surely I will have a play with it.But in my case I want to make it work only with first options. I am not in a position to update my firmware right now.
I have tried all the three self timer modes to achieve it and it is not working right now. so it would be great if you could please suggest me how to achieve it using Canon T2i's Drive setting alone without any addon.

Comment: Finally I updated my camera to magic lantern and it solved my never ending problem :)

Comment: I cannot open the option to change the interval between poctures. 10 sec is default and no way how to change it...